# How to switch tabs with a German keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, language

**Context:** Most native macOS apps use
<kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> for switching to the next and previous tabs respectively.

**Problem:** However this does not work for German keyboards. To type a <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>]</kbd> with a German keybord, you have to press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> or <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> respectively.

**Question:** How to switch tabs with a German keyboard?

Comment: Do Control-tab and Control-shift-tab work for Safari?

Comment: Thank you very much @TomGewecke. This works perfectly for the applications I tested (Safari, Firefox, Atom). Do you want to add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to switch tabs via the alternative shortcuts <kbd>⌃ control</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>⌃ control</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>.

Comment: Much more ergonomic shortcuts to remember.